# tmap in R is ignoring my "breaks" argument for discrete buckets

Tags: r, tmap

I am making a world heatmap from a dataset where the values of one country are -1 and the rest are values from 0 to 10. I tried to make 5 discrete buckets by making a palette of 5 colors and a breaks argument with 6 integers in a vector.

```
robin <- "+proj=robin +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

map = tm_shape(mapdata, projection = robin, bbox = boundaries) +
  tm_polygons("Sum.of.increase", # style = "fixed",
              breaks = c(-Inf, 0, .5, 1, 2, Inf),
              palette = c("white","#FF7C80", "wheat1", "#ADDC9C", "#6AC04A"), colorNA = "grey",
              legend.show = TRUE) + 
  tm_layout (frame = FALSE, bg.color = "transparent") + 
#  tmap_options(max.categories = 5)
map
```

I can see from the legend that it seems to be totally disregarding my buckets.

[image: legend]

I have tried with more values in the breaks vector, I've added style = fixed, and I've added tmap_options max.categories to no avail.

Commenting out the line with the breaks argument results in the exact same output map/legend.

Debugging details:
Desired behavior: The map and legend should reflect that the buckets I have defined are respected: -Infinity to 0, 0 to 0.5, 0.5 to 1, 1 to 2, 2 to infinity

```
R.Version()
$platform
[1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "mingw32"

$crt
[1] "ucrt"

$system
[1] "x86_64, mingw32"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "4"

$minor
[1] "2.1"

$year
[1] "2022"

$month
[1] "06"

$day
[1] "23"

$`svn rev`
[1] "82513"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)"

$nickname
[1] "Funny-Looking Kid"
```

Comment: **Needs debugging details**  
The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: If I try breaks with `Inf` I get an error and without `Inf` it works as intended. 
I don't know your data but it might make sense to handle infinite values somehow beforehand so you don't run into this issue.

Comment: I actually don't have values outside of [-1, 10] but I wasn't able to get it to work and just added the `Inf`s later. I will switch the code back though now that you say that, that's helpful to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue: the variable being plotted was class "character" rather than numeric.

To diagnose: `summary(mapdata$Sum.of.increase)`

Results:

```
Length     Class      Mode 
173 character character
```

To fix:

`mapdata$Sum.of.increase = as.numeric(mapdata$Sum.of.increase)`

Confirmation:

```
> summary(mapdata$Sum.of.increase)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
-1.0000  0.4068  0.7621  2.1974  1.2964 10.0000      37
```

To summarize, if some function is ignoring your breaks, make sure the variable is numeric as apparently breaks don't work on strings even though R can interpret and graph them.